# Freezing on 23.04 and it does it randomly

Tags: freeze

I had to use sysreq combos to restart my laptop every time it would freeze on me. i have ***24GB of RAM*** an *i5-7300HQ* and a *NVidia GTX 1050* so it should be a performance problem. I also have 256GB of SSD NVME and 1 TB of HDD storage. i would only have Opera, Discord open and then it would mostly crash. It does it randomly. **I dont understand how to use commands to increase memory.**

Comment: "so it should be a performance problem" I do not understand that conclusion. Random crashes where the system halts is a hardware problem and if it is really random the most logical problem is faulty memory. 1st thing to do is check the memory modules for errors.  In all other cases a crash tends to stop the offending app but the other apps and the system continue to operate. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest

Comment: i checked my memory and everything was okay it operated without any problems, and i made a typo; it was supposed to be "so it *shouldn't* be a performance problem.

Comment: cool :)  then you will need to go through crash reports if those are there. There is a /var/crash/  It can have reports of memory dumps that will contain specifications about the crash.